# No ping response, still transmitting data

Tags: tcpip

Why would a device with a static ip not respond to a ping, but still transmit information over the network?

In my situation the device is a very simple caller ID box. It has no GUI. It's only purpose is to parse CID information and transmit the information where applicable.

Comment: This will likely be closed because it is far too broad. We have no way to know *why* unless the developers themselves provide an answer, and to randomly speculate in the meantime is outside the scope of [SU]. That said, many devices do not respond to PING for a number of reasons, such as wanting to appear offline to anyone attempting to probe them, or simply because the developers didn't program in a PING function.

Answer (score 3):

An ip capable device doesn't have to implement ping at all.

Especially very simple devices, with very limited functionality, don't do anything not strictly necessary for what they need to do.

It just keeps the software simple (less potential for bugs) and as tiny as possible (less ROM/RAM needed). As a result it will be cheaper to manufacture (in man-hours for programming/debugging and in material costs).

In bigger, more complex equipment the ip-stack is often bought as a, ready to go, commodity-module and the RAM/ROM needed is usually already present because of other requirements.
Then there is often a full ip-stack present, with a ssh or web-interface for configuration and other niceties, because it doesn't cost any extra to implement.

Answer (score 2):

The device (or some intermediate device on the network) could be blocking ICMP traffic without blocking other traffic.